# My flow of code is not entering into if loop in django views.py

Tags: python, django

This is the part of code in django views.py , the flow of code is not entering into if loop and directly entering into else and creating problems. Why it is not entering into if(w == '3 Standard Deviation') , this loop ? I want to check if w or z == 3 Standard Deviation or 2 Standard Deviation then save csv file to respective static folder .

---

```
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    global path_of_uploaded_csv
    if request.method == 'POST':
        UploadedData = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if UploadedData.is_valid():
            # Dataframe
            try:
                dataframe = pd.read_csv(request.FILES['file'])
            except:
                return render(request, 'home.html', {'message': True})

            No_of_Rows = dataframe.shape[0]

            d_frame = request.FILES['file']
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

            # File Storage on Disks
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            fs.save(d_frame.name, d_frame)

            # list of columns
            df = dataframe.select_dtypes(exclude=["bool_", "object_"])
            list_for_pop = df.columns
            import csv
            path_of_uploaded_csv = request.FILES['file']

            import json
            json_object = {list_for_pop.get_loc(
                c): c for idx, c in enumerate(list_for_pop)}

            path_of_uploaded_csv.flush()
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'DataFrame': dataframe, 'item': list_for_pop, 'path': path_of_uploaded_csv, 'json_response': json_object, 'noOfRows': No_of_Rows})

        elif(request.POST.get):
            # Dependent dropdown
            try:
                dpost_list = request.POST.getlist('dropdown1')
            except:
                return render(request, 'home.html', {'warning1': True})

            print(dpost_list)

            # Independent Dropdown
            try:
                ipost_list = request.POST.getlist('dropdown2')
            except:
                return render(request, 'home.html', {'warning2': True})

            w = request.POST.getlist('3std')
            z = request.POST.getlist('2std')

            #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

            df_path = request.POST.get('path')
            # print(df_path + '============= df_path ===================')

            try:
                dataframe = pd.read_csv(df_path)
            except:
                return render(request, 'home.html', {'warning5': True})

            try:
                var1 = toInitializeOutlierDetection(
                    dpost_list, ipost_list, dataframe)
            except:
                return render(request, 'home.html', {'warning3': True})

            # var3 = (z[0] == '2 Standard Deviation') if True Conn_CheckBox1(var1) else Conn_CheckBox2(var1)
            try:
                import pdb
                pdb.set_trace()
                var3 = Conn_CheckBox1(var1) if (
                    (z == '2 Standard Deviation') is True) else Conn_CheckBox2(var1)
                # print(var3)

            except:
                return render(request, 'home.html', {'warning4': True})

            #global var4
            var4 = detectOutliers()
            from django.conf import settings
            from django.conf.urls.static import static
            import os
            path = '/home/gaurav/Desktop/Deployment Folder/Outlier_Detection /static'

            if(w == '3 Standard Deviation'):
                print('working')
                import pdb
                pdb.set_trace()
                var4.to_csv(
                    r'/home/gaurav/Desktop/Deployment Folder/Outlier_Detection /static/3_Standard_Deviation.csv', encoding='utf-8')

            # elif(w == '3 Standard Deviation'):
            else:
                #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                var4.to_csv(
                    r'/home/gaurav/Desktop/Deployment Folder/Outlier_Detection /static/2_Standard_Deviation.csv', encoding='utf-8')

            return render(request, 'home.html', {'DataFrame': var4, 'path': path, 'message1': True})
```

Comment: Did you checked what's coming in your variable **w**? try printing content of request.POST and check for the key that you are trying to get, is it coming like "3std[]"?

Comment: yes it is 3 Stanndard Deviation

Comment: did you checked for any whitespaces in case? by using len for "w" and your constant string?

Comment: <QueryDict: {'dropdown1': ['studytime'], 'dropdown2': ['traveltime', 'freetime', 'goout'], '3std': ['3 Standard Deviation'], 'path': ['StudentsTest.csv']}>

Comment: (Pdb) print(w)
['3 Standard Deviation']

Comment: "w" is a list type but you are comparing it with a string type so that's why it's going in else block as given from your above logs.